# Select file to populate userform with tabs, to select Worksheets to copy to active Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I need to copy tabs/worksheets to the active workbook.

I would like to use VBA filedialog, to choose a file, have the tabs in this file show in a user form, and select which tabs to copy/move to the active workbook.

This code only lists the sheet names of the selected sheet in the active workbook.

```vb
Dim FilePicker As FileDialog
Dim mypath As String
Dim sheet_name As String
Dim sheet_count As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, sht As String, arr() As String, n As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set FilePicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With FilePicker
    .Title = "Please Select a File"
    .ButtonName = "Confirm"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = -1 Then
        mypath = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        End
    End If
End With

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer, sht As String, arr() As String, n As Long
   
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
            ReDim Preserve arr(n)
            arr(n) = ListBox1.List(i)
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Sheets(arr).Copy
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ListBox1
        For sh = 1 To Sheets.Count
            .AddItem ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sh).Name
        Next sh
        .MultiSelect = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

I tried this code in a user form, but it doesn't pull the tabs in the selected workbook into the user form. I get a blank user form.

Comment: You code only ask the user to select a file - it doesn't do anything beyond that.  You need to open the workbook, loop over the worksheets, and add them to a listbox.  Eg see: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-let-user-choose-multiple-sheets-in-workbook-from-list-and-copy-to-new-workbook.1213517/

Comment: Hi Tim - Thank you for your response.  I tried using the code you provided, however, I can only copy selected worksheets to a new workbook and not the active workbook.  To be clear, I want to find and open the workbook with the tabs I need, have the tabs populate in a listbox and then select what can be moved/copied to the active workbook.  Do you have any further suggestions please?

Comment: Please update your post with your current code, showing what was added from the link I posted - that will help fix the problem.  In the linked code it has `Sheets(arr).Copy` but you want to copy to your current workbook, so maybe `Sheets(arr).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)`

Comment: Here you go: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set FilePicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With FilePicker
.Title = "Please Select a File"
.ButtonName = "Confirm"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show = -1 Then
mypath = .SelectedItems(1)
Else
End
End If

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
            ReDim Preserve arr(n)
            arr(n) = ListBox1.List(i)
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Sheets(arr).Copy
After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    Unload Me
End With

Comment: Please *edit your question* to add the code there...  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76732174/edit

Comment: Hi Tim - code has been added to original question.  Did what I could to fit it in?  Please provide solution when you can.  Thanks.

Comment: `mypath` is the selected file, but you don't open the file or load its sheet names into the listbox?

Comment: Yes - I am trying to load the workbook I select to the list box. This is the solution I want to arrive at. Not too skilled in VBA so the code might be a bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim wb As Workbook

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer, sht As String, arr() As String, n As Long
   
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
            ReDim Preserve arr(n)
            arr(n) = ListBox1.List(i)
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next i
    wb.Sheets(arr).Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    wb.Close   '?
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = GetSelectedWorkbook() 'ask user to pick a file
    
    If wb Is Nothing Then 'no file selected
        MsgBox "No file selected!"
        Exit Sub
        Unload Me
    End If
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        ListBox1.AddItem ws.Name
    Next ws
    ListBox1.MultiSelect = 1
    
End Sub

Function GetSelectedWorkbook() As Workbook
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Title = "Please Select an Excel File"
        .ButtonName = "Confirm"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then Set GetSelectedWorkbook = _
                        Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Tim -Sorry for the late response. This works perfect!! Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: Thanks for the update - please flag as "Accepted" to help anyone else coming along later with a similar problem.